# Can't hide HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an oddly difficult hiding an html table with javascript/jQuery. I've tried both of the following:

```
document.getElementById('tblQuickTools').style.display = 'none';
$('#tblQuickTools').hide();
```

I've stepped through the code to make sure the lines are being hit. The HTML for the table is below.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="38%" id="tblQuickTools">
    <tr>
        <td class="outerTableTopLeftSmall">
        </td>
        <td colspan="4" class="outerTableTopRepeatSmall">
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableTopRightSmall">
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableTopLeftSmall">
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="outerTableTopRepeatSmall">
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableTopRightSmall">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="outerTableLeftRepeatSmall">
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <img src="identity.gif" border="0" />
            <strong><big>Quick Tools</big> </strong>
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableRightRepeatSmall">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="outerTableLeftRepeatSmall">
        </td>
        <td colspan="4">
            <strong>
                <hr />
            </strong>
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableRightRepeatSmall">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="outerTableLeftRepeatSmall">
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="btnDownloadAll" onclick="LaunchSignOffMultiDownloader(this);this.blur();return false;"
                href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnMed"><span>Download All</span> </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="btnReplaceAll" onclick="LaunchSignOffMultiUploader(this, true);this.blur();return false;"
                href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnMed"><span>Replace All</span> </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a id="btnRetainAll" onclick="RetainAllSignOffDocuments();this.blur();return false;"
                href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnMed"><span>Retain All</span> </a>
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableRightRepeatSmall">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="outerTableBotLeftSmall">
        </td>
        <td colspan="4" class="outerTableBotRepeatSmall">
        </td>
        <td class="outerTableBotRightSmall">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I checked and tblQuickTools is loaded. So it's not a loading issue. I could try using $(document).ready() but I'm apprehensive about it. tblQuickTools is inside a tab which is inside an aspx page which sits in a Master Page. The tab is loaded through AJAX when clicked on. The hide code runs in the tabLoaded() function. If I used $(document).ready() I'm not sure which document ready it would fire on, the tab, the page or the master page.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/5t9q9/ are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: How are you trying to hide it? Show how you try to trigger that code.

Comment: don't forget , you cannot hide something that is not actually exist.

Comment: Your code will work if you put it at the end of your HTML body.

Comment: @David You're talking about 2 different things. The link you posted refers to putting a `<script>` **outside** of the `<body>` (and `<head>`), which is the invalid part. And there's reasons for using either `$(document).ready()` or putting script at the end of the `<body>`, so unless you have specific reasoning, don't suggest it

Comment: better of adding a class to the html element and hide it that way
.myspecialclass #tblQuickTools {display:none}
you can add the class via js or jquery

Comment: @JamesDaly It might be better to add the class to the `<body>` tag - I know IE has had problems in the past with normal attributes on the `<html>` element. Not a big deal, I've just stayed away from that

Comment: @Ian - I believe Modernizer adds it to the html element - that's why you need to put modernizer within the head; but body or head I believe it's all semantics

Comment: OK. I checked and tblQuickTools is loaded. So it's not a loading issue. I could try using $(document).ready() but I'm apprehensive about it. tblQuickTools is inside a tab which is inside an aspx page which sits in a Master Page. The tab is loaded through AJAX when clicked on. The hide code runs in the tabLoaded() function. If I used $(document).ready() I'm not sure which document ready it would fire on, the tab, the page or the master page.

Comment: @JamesDaly Yeah, ignore what I said. I used to add a class to the `<html>` element, and I thought I read somewhere about it having problems in IE. But I also often see conditional comments used to add classes to the `<html>` element (obviously **for IE**). So maybe I'm thinking of something else (like specifically using `document.documentElement` to manipulate the class) which may be a "problem" in IE, but I can't see why. I know a lot of things work on the `<html>` so that obviously seems fine

Comment: if it's a dynamic element you'll need to use event delegation
$("body").on("click", "#yourtab", function(){
$('#tblQuickTools').hide()
})

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to hide this table just after page is displayed, it might not be there yet. If this is the case, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tblQuickTools').hide();
});
```

It will launch `$('#tblQuickTools').hide();` after the page is completely rendered.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with JavaScript (after the document loads, as pointed out), but you'd really be better off styling it hidden:

```
<head>
<style>

  #tblQuickTools { display:none }

</style>
</head>
```

This will eliminate any flickering that may occur with the JS version.